# NsdManager not finding http server

Tags: android

I'm running a simple http server on my local network and trying to use NsdManager from an Android device to discover it. I've followed the [Android training guide on this matter](http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd.html#discover), but my device is not finding any services.

Here's my Android code:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
private void setupNetworkDiscovery()
{
    discoveryListener = new NsdManager.DiscoveryListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onStopDiscoveryFailed(String serviceType, int errorCode)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartDiscoveryFailed(String serviceType, int errorCode)
        {
            Log.d(getPackageName(), "Start failed");

        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceLost(NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceFound(NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo)
        {
            Log.d(getPackageName(), "Found a service");

            // display the service info
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(serviceInfo.toString());
            sb.append(" - name: ");
            sb.append(serviceInfo.getServiceName());
            sb.append("; type: ");
            sb.append(serviceInfo.getServiceType());
            sb.append("\n");
            servicesLabel.append(sb.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onDiscoveryStopped(String serviceType)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onDiscoveryStarted(String serviceType)
        {
            Log.d(getPackageName(), "Start succeeded");
        }
    };

    nsdManager = (NsdManager) getSystemService(Context.NSD_SERVICE);
    nsdManager.discoverServices("_http._tcp", NsdManager.PROTOCOL_DNS_SD, discoveryListener);
}
```

The only log message I get is "Start succeeded" from *onDiscoveryStarted*.

The server is certainly running, as I can connect to it using a browser. nmap also confirms the port is open:

```
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.104
Host is up (0.00011s latency).
PORT     STATE SERVICE
8080/tcp open  http-proxy
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello Andrei, have you found a solution? I'm stuck with the same issue.

Comment: I did not. I abandoned this avenue soon after I saw I wasn't getting any answers and haven't worked on this since. Sorry I can't help much.

Comment: I ended up doing a "brute force" approuch. Looping through the last bit IP's of the network, with a very short connection timeout. It's working OK so far.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's your primary issue, but the service type should be "_http._tcp."
(you are missing the dot at the end)
For me (API 21), your code works fine, discovering "_http._tcp" still returns the services that are "_http._tcp."

Comment: Hi @travisa, are you able to find all list of connected to network. Thanks in advance